# Is there a function like char::escape_default for u8 bytes?

Tags: rust, escaping

The Rust standard library has a `char::escape_default` function which will print the literal character if it's printable, or a sensible escape sequence (`\n`, `\u{XXXX}`, etc.) if not.

Is there an equivalent for bytes? Specifically, I would like it to return the literal byte if it's printable, or return a **byte** escape sequence (`\xNN`) if not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard library has a [`std::ascii::escape_default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ascii/fn.escape_default.html) function that satisfies this use case:

```rust
fn main() {
    let x = String::from_utf8(
        "The compiler said “you have an error!”."
            .bytes()
            .flat_map(|b| std::ascii::escape_default(b))
            .collect::<Vec<u8>>(),
    )
    .unwrap();
    println!("{}", x);
}
```